# What tag to use to discuss FLDIGI?

Tags: discussion

I am new to [FLDIGI](http://www.w1hkj.com/FldigiHelp-3.22/index.html) and want to exchange experience/lessons learned on stackexchange. What is the best tag to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about tags too much; make your best guess and people will fix them for you.

In this particular case the appropriate tags would be [digital](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digital) and [software](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software). If there came to be many questions about fldigi it would make sense to create [fldigi](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fldigi) then.

(Also, when you want to ask a question *about asking questions*, you should post it on [meta](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't worry about this one; I've already requested it be migrated.)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: Note that participate on meta requires a minimum of 5 rep.